# Java Script change Path Dynamically With onClick

Tags: symfony

```
for(var j=0;j<data[0].length;j++){

    tabl1.append( "<tr><div><td></td><a><td id='aa"+j+"' onClick=\"document.location.href='{{ path('u_files',{'oc':"+data[0][j].name+"}) }}'\">"+data[0][j].name+"</td></a><td>"+data[0][j].size+
    </td><td>"+data[0][j].lastmodified+"</td><td></td></div></tr>" );
}
```

my problem is that the variable `data[0][j].name` inside the path won't be interpreted it should give me the following response :

```
path('u_files',{'oc':amine})
```

but instead it gives me the following url :
http://localhost:8080/app_dev.php/u_files/+data%5B0%5D%5Bj%5D.name+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mess up back-end with front-end. Twig function won't ever receive Javascript argument this way.

I'd recommend to do something like this:

```js
var tpl = '{{ path('u_files',{'oc':'%%%'}) }}';

// inside setting the onclick:
tpl.replace('\%\%\%', data[0][j].name);
```

Comment: var tmp = '{{ path('user_files',{'oc':'%%%%'}) }}';
                      for(var j=0;j<data[0].length;j++){
                        tmp.replace('%%%%', data[0][j].name);

                        tabl1.append( "<tr><div><td></td><a><td id='aa"+j+"' onClick='document.location.href="+tmp+"'>"+data[0][j].name+"</td></a><td>"+data[0][j].size+
                          "</td><td>"+data[0][j].lastmodified+"</td><td></td></div></tr>" );
                      }                /*i'v tried something like this but it wont work neither

Comment: You have to replace ``data[0][j].name`` in ``append`` argument with the last line I posted.

Comment: i'v replaced it the document.location.href ="+tmp" , the other data[0][j].name is working fine

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've overseen. What do you mean "won't work"? Any errors? Stacktrace?

Comment: when i click on the td element Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags

Comment: So put a checkmark on my answer to indicate it's correct.